# Converting NSpoint and passing the values in to CGRectMake

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, nspoint

I am getting a point in NSPoint as:

```
NSPoint: {273,534}
```

I want to pass 273 and 534 into `CGrectMake`.
For example:

```
viewTwo.frame=CGRectMake(273,534,someValue,someValue)
```

I am not able to get the values in that `NSpoint`.
I tried passing it to NsArray and NSDictionary. Nothing works. Pls help

I use Po command in console and found the value which i need is in NSPoint. But dont know how to convert it

Comment: `CGPoint` maybe, instead of `NSPoint`? If you have a `CGPoint`, use `yourPoint.x` and `yourPoint.y`?

Comment: no its a 3rd party framwork i get point in NSPoints

Comment: But how do you receive it? As a Nsstring?

Comment: i tried Bridge and tried converting it but dint work

Comment: no i am yet to receive it. I use Po command in console and found the value which i need is in NSPoint. But dont know how to convert it

Comment: You can't be getting an `NSPoint` in an iOS app. iOS doesn't have `NSPoint`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSPoint is a Mac OS type. I don't think it's defined in iOS. In iOS you can just cast an NSPoint to a CGPoint:

```
//Probably not valid in iOS because NSPoint isn't defined, but is shows a variable
NSPoint somePoint = MakePoint(273,534); 

//Cast an NSPoint to a CGPoint in order to get at it's values...
viewTwo.frame=CGRectMake(273,534,((CGPoint)somePoint).x,((CGPoint)somePoint).y);
```

Answer (score 4):

Assume that you have this:

```
NSValue *point = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(273, 534)];
```

It will output like this in console:

```
NSPoint: {273,534}
```

So you can create CGRect like this

```
viewTwo.frame=CGRectMake([point CGPointValue].x, [point CGPointValue].y, someValue, someValue);
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `NSPoint` in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
NSPoint somePoint; 
// Assuming this point got its value from some function.
viewTwo.frame = CGRectMake(somePoint.x, somePoint.y, myWidth, myHeight);
```

Comment: u cannot find a NSPoint type

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing an import for the Foundation framework somewhere? In projects created in Xcode 6+, there's no default precompiled header so more framework headers have to be imported manually; although NSPoint should just work fine.

Comment: There is no such thing as NSPoint in iOS.

Comment: Correct, but there is on OSX :-). CGPoint, CGRect, etc have NS... equivalents when developing an OSX app.

Comment: The question is tagged iOS. So the answer should be appropriate for iOS. You can't import the header for `NSPoint` in an iOS app.

Comment: @rmaddy must have overlooked that, though he does state that he gets NSPoints from a framework, perhaps the framework in question was meant for OSX?